# Is it necessary to have a separate CA server to be online 24/7 in order to provide signing service for another OpenVPN server?

Tags: rsa, digital-ocean, openvpn, certificate-authority

I had followed a [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) and deployed OpenVPN & CA servers (EasyRSA) for my team in order to remotely access some infrastructure; and this has worked very well for us.

However, I am new to OpenVPN and Certificate Authorities, so I don't exactly understand how they interact with each other - I just followed the tutorial.

My questions:

1. Why do I need to deploy a whole CA server on the internet instead of simply signing keys with my Local PC or some local VM?
2. Does this CA server have to be online 24/7, or do I only run it when I need to sign new client keys?

Aside from gaining technical knowledge, I also want to reduce the cost by not running this CA server all the time, hence my two questions.

Things I learned:

- [OpenVPN documentation](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/GettingStartedwithOVPN#Configuringencryption) clearly explains why the CA has to be a different machine for security purposes, but not whether this service must always be online.
- I tested connecting to the VPN while the CA server is offline, and the VPN connection worked. - I still don't understand what's going on exactly from CA perspective when a clients connects.

Thanks for checking my question.

Comment: Online means "connected to the network", and nothing in that article says the CA server has to be online *ever*, let alone 24/7. The first mention of it says: *Note ... that it’s recommended that you keep the CA server turned off when not being used to sign keys...* The function of the CA is covered in any one of numerous off-site tutotials.

Comment: I understood that CA server is used by clients to verify identity of the peer, I can't wrap my head around the CA server being turned off and still achieve this functionality without communicating/responding to the clients?

Comment: You're making assumptions about the role of the CA that are not correct. That's why it's a good idea to first examine one of those tutorials I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I'll examine them first! @PresidentJamesK.Polk